# Momentum of Eigenstate of Spin Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, eigenvalue

For the Hamiltonian $H = \dfrac{p^2}{2m} - \mu S_z$, the eigenstates are the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $. I understand these are eigenvectors of $S_z$. I was wondering however what the momentum of these states are. Would they be $0$, since differentiation by the momentum operator on a constant vector is $0$?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Those are not all the eigenstates of this Hamiltonian. Hint: $p$ and $S_z$ are compatible observables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Momentum and spin degrees of freedom are not coupled here (i.e. there is no *spin-orbit coupling*), so the wave functions are product of momentum and spin eigenfunctions (aka *separation of variables, although with spin it may look unusual):
$$\psi_{\mathbf{k},\uparrow} = e^{i\mathbf{kr}}\chi_\uparrow,\\
\psi_{\mathbf{k},\downarrow} = e^{i\mathbf{kr}}\chi_\downarrow.$$
There is an interesting class of related exercise problems where an electron polarized along z-axis passes through a region of a constant magnetic field oriented along the x-axis. I kin of magnetic square well. It is discussed, e.g., in [Flugge's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540650355).